# An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list

Tags: mysql

Hey guys I'm trying to find product list prices which is higher than the double average ListPrice of products in their category. I did a similar question like this and I used a HAVING clause to solve it but this one is not working. Any suggestions on what Im doing wrong ?

```
SELECT P.Name             NameOfProduct,
       PC.Name            NameOfProductCategory,
       P.ListPrice        ProductListPrice, 
       AVG(P.ListPrice)   AverageListPrice 
FROM   Product P 
   INNER JOIN ProductCategory PC ON (PC.ProductCategoryID = P.ProductCategoryID)
WHERE (P.ListPrice) > (AVG(P.ListPrice)*2) 
GROUP BY P.Name, PC.Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, you cannot use aggregation functions in the `having` clause.  You can do what you want using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT P.Name             NameOfProduct,
       PC.Name            NameOfProductCategory,
       P.ListPrice        ProductListPrice, 
       AVG(P.ListPrice)   AverageListPrice 
FROM Product P INNER JOIN
     ProductCategory PC
     ON PC.ProductCategoryID = P.ProductCategoryID
WHERE P.ListPrice) > (SELECT AVG(p2.ListPrice)*2
                      FROM Product p2
                      WHERE p2.ProductCategoryID = p.ProductCategoryID
                     )
GROUP BY P.Name, PC.Name, P.ListPrice;
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a bunch Gordon! I added P.ListPrice in the GROUP BY clause and the query worked perfectly!